# Program doesn't step into method

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to figure out why my program doesn't seem to be stepping into one of my methods: assignKennel(). Instead, it keeps asking for more input, even though theres more to do in the while loop. Any advice will be much appreciated. I'm not sure what to include, so here is all I have.

```
    package finalbarking;

    import java.util.InputMismatchException;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Finalbarking {

    //global int numberOfDogs, numberOfKennels;
    static int numberOfDogs, numberOfKennels=8;
      //int dogID
       static int [] dogIDs= new int [15];
            //add provided ID's

        //String dogNames
       static String [] dogNames= new String [15];

            //add provided dogs to array


        //int dogWeights
       static int [] dogWeights= new int [15];
            //add provided weights to array
      //at start, this is empty.
      //array size = 8 elements myArray = new int[7]
        //int KennelNumber
      static  int [] kennelNumbers= new int [8];
        //String kennelWeight(SMALL / MEDIUM / LARGE)
      static  String [] kennelWeight= new String [3];

        //int dogInKennelID
       static int [] dogInKennelID= new int [8];
        static int inputDogID=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
   //vars
   //Scanner
   Scanner response= new Scanner(System.in);
   //int inputDogID

   dogIDs[0]=1001;
   dogIDs[1]=1003;
   dogIDs[2]=1007;
   dogIDs[3]=1008;
   dogIDs[4]=1012;
   dogIDs[5]=1034;
   dogIDs[6]=1038;
   dogIDs[7]=1087;
   dogIDs[8]=1088;
   dogIDs[9]=1120;
   dogIDs[10]=1129;
   dogIDs[11]=1145;
   dogIDs[12]=1200;
   dogIDs[13]=1211;
   dogIDs[14]=1222;
  dogNames[0]= "Bowser";
  dogNames[1]= "Ginger";
  dogNames[2]= "Molly";
  dogNames[3]= "Murphy";
  dogNames[4]= "Roxy";
  dogNames[5]= "Samantha";
  dogNames[6]= "Duke";
  dogNames[7]= "Pookie";
  dogNames[8]= "Abby";
  dogNames[9]= "Barney";
  dogNames[10]= "Autumn";
  dogNames[11]= "Hershey";
  dogNames[12]= "King";
  dogNames[13]= "Bosco";
  dogNames[14]= "Daisy";
  dogWeights[0]=130;
  dogWeights[1]=80;
  dogWeights[2]=45;
  dogWeights[3]=18;
  dogWeights[4]=70;
  dogWeights[5]=12;
  dogWeights[6]=90;
  dogWeights[7]=16;
  dogWeights[8]=35;
  dogWeights[9]=65;
  dogWeights[10]=20;
  dogWeights[11]=100;
  dogWeights[12]=110;
  dogWeights[13]=70;
  dogWeights[14]=55;
  kennelWeight[0] = "SMALL";
  kennelWeight[1] = "MEDIUM";
  kennelWeight[2]= "LARGE";

                //reset at end

   //Greeting for employee
        System.out.println("Hello Barking Lot Employee!");
   //begin loop
   while(inputDogID!=9999){
    //try
    try{
    //prompt for  dog id, 9999 as sentinel value
       System.out.println("Please enter the dog's ID number, or '9999' to quit)");
        //capture
        inputDogID= response.nextInt();
   //end try start catch exception
    }catch(InputMismatchException error){
        //Invalid
                System.err.println("You've entered an invalid Dog ID. Try again(Please refer to our Dog Client List, they are all 4 digits long).");
                //pause program
                Thread.sleep(10);
                //reset scanner
                response = new Scanner(System.in);
    }//end catch

    int foundDogID = 0;

    for(int count=0; count<15; count++)
    {
       if(dogIDs[count] == inputDogID){
          foundDogID = count;
       }//end if
    }//end for

     currentClients(dogIDs,dogNames,dogWeights,inputDogID);
    //assignKennel()
    assignKennel(foundDogID);
   //displayKennel();
    displayKennel();


   }//endwhile 

    }//end main
  //User Defined Methods
    //CurrentClients- Identifies dog based on list of current clients
    public static void currentClients(int[]dogIDs,String[]dogNames,int[]dogWeights,int inputDogID){
        //Takes 3 arrays(ID, NAME, WEIGHT)
        //Takes inputDogID
        //Iterate the array and check if inputDogID == ID[count]
        //for(int count = 0; count < numberOfDogs; count++)
        for(int count = 0; count <= numberOfDogs; count ++){



            //if(inputDogID == ID) then return NAME + WEIGHT;
            if(inputDogID==dogIDs[count]){
                System.out.println("Dog Name : "+dogNames[count]+"\tDog Weight: "+ dogWeights[count]);
            }//end if
            //else then return 0 and display an error
            else
                System.out.println("Did not find a dog matching this ID Number.");

        }//end for
    }//endCurrentClients
    //assignKennel-assigns dogs to kennels
    public static void assignKennel(int dogIDs){


        //takes 1 int dogID
        //Iterate the array and check:
        //var
        boolean didDogGetKennel=false;
        for(int count = 0; count < numberOfKennels; count++){
        //if(getDogWeightClass(dogWeights[dogID]).equals(kennelWeight[count]))
        String weightClass = getDogWeightClass(dogWeights[dogIDs]);
        for(int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
        {
           if(weightClass.equals(kennelWeight[counter]))
           {
              if(dogInKennelID[count] == 0){
                       //then EMPTY, assign 
                           didDogGetKennel=true;
                           dogInKennelID[count]=dogIDs;
                   }//end if 
              }
        }

        }//end for loop
           //if didDogGetKennel=false display message: "I'm sorry all ken
           if(didDogGetKennel==false)
               System.out.println("I'm sorry, all of our kennels for that weight limit are filled.");
    }//end assignKennel
//displayKennel- displays the eight kennel numbers &the dog assigned to each
     public static void displayKennel(){
    // print if all kennels are filled 
    if(areKennelsFull()){
            for(int count =0; count<=8; count ++)
             System.out.println(kennelNumbers[count] + getDogName(dogInKennelID[count]));
    }//end if
//else if print if sentinel value is enter
    else if(inputDogID==9999){
            for(int count =0; count<=8; count ++)
            System.out.println(kennelNumbers[count] + getDogName(dogInKennelID[count]));
    }//end else if
     }//end displayKennel
//getDogWeightClass()
    public static String getDogWeightClass(int dogWeight){
        //take int dog weight
        //if dog weight < 50, then SMALL
        if(dogWeight<50)
            return "SMALL";
        //else if dog weight >50 &&<100 then MEDIUM
        else if(dogWeight>50 &&dogWeight <100)
            return "MEDIUM";
        //else then LARGE
        else
            return "LARGE";
        //return String S/M/L


    }//end getDogWeightClass
     //getDogName()
    public static String getDogName(int dogInKennelID){
        //take dogInKennelID
        return dogNames[dogInKennelID];

    }//end getDogName
    //areKennelsFull()
    public static Boolean areKennelsFull(){
    for(int count =0; count<=8; count ++){
        if (dogInKennelID[count] ==0)
            return false;
         //return boolean false 
        //else return boolean true
        else
            return true;

    }//end for
           return false;
    }//end areKennelsFull

}//end class
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually does run `assignKennel()`. If you put a `System.out.println()` statement in there to verify that that method runs, you'll see that it does. The problem isn't with that method; every method is running as it should.

Your problem is in `displayKennel()`. It isn't doing anything. `areKennelsFull()` evaluates to `false`, as does `inputDogID==9999` (assuming some other id was typed in). I'm guessing `areKennelsFull()` is supposed to evaluate to `true` after a valid ID has been entered, so the root cause of this problem is most likely either in `areKennelsFull()` or perhaps in `assignKennels()` incorrectly assigning a value somewhere in `dogInKennelID`.

Comment: See, it does print and the end, but it looks like its not assigning to the right kennel. It only assigns one, to 0. If another ID is entered, it glitches.

Comment: Okay, I think I've found your problem. It's actually in the main method. It's with this statement in the for loop: `foundDogID = count`. If you input 1001, then `foundDogID` is 0 because `dogIDs[0]` is equal to 1001. This value then gets passed on to `assignKennel()`, which then assigns 0 somewhere in `dogInKennelID`. `areKennelsFull()` sees that this value is 0 and consequently returns `false`, which is causing the problem you're having.

Comment: Another issue I've noticed with this is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. That's occurring in `displayKennel()` here: `for(int count =0; count<= 8; count ++)`. The terminating condition for the for loop should be `count < 8`, since `kennelNumbers[8]` and `dogInKennelID[8]` do not exist. Keep in mind that counting in Java is zero-based, so an array of size 8 will have indices 0-7, not 1-8.

Comment: By the way, I am aware of the "Did not find a dog matching this ID Number" problem. I just haven't mentioned it because I haven't been able to figure out yet what's causing that to appear when certain valid IDs are entered.

Answer (score 0):

It does enter that routine, but one problem I see is that you are exceeding the array index.  You have the condition "count<=8" in 3 for statements which should read "count<8" (remove the "=").  When it tries to use index 8, it bombs, and so the program cannot finish properly.  The array is indexed from 0 to 7, so 8 is invalid.